# Download HTML as Zip Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm using the google drive API to download a google sheet. Unfortunately I need to download it as an HTML to embed in an email however when I run

```
export_request = drivesrvc.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='application/zip')
fh = io.FileIO("data.zip", "wb")
downloader = apiclient.http.MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, export_request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print
    "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

The request goes through, but the zip file is empty! If I try any other file format it works just fine but the zip is always empty for some reason and I need to get the HTML.

The documentation specifies that the above call should return a Zip archive containing HTML files corresponding the the worksheets in the google sheet, yet all I get is an empty Zip archive.

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve HTML and save it as a.zip file? That’s not going to be a valid zip file.

Comment: The Google drive API has the option to export the spreadsheet to a zip archive with HTML files in it corresponding to worksheets in the Google sheet. I am trying to do that but it always returns an empty zip file whereas the other export options (excel, pdf, csv, etc) work just fine. There is no option to just download the HTML directly, it must always come in a zip archive.

Comment: I think you're program is just doing what you're telling it, download it as a zip file, not put it in a zip file and download it. Same thing happens if you download it as mimetype img/jpeg, etc.

Comment: According to the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) on their API this should return a zip containing the spreadsheet in HTML format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced same issue, You can try the below code. It worked for me!

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<sheetid>/export?format=zip"
response = drivesrvc._http.request(url)
with open(os.path.join("data.zip"), "wb") as wer:
   for res in response:
      wer.write(str(res))
```

Comment: Ended up taking an alternate approach to my problem. Just tried this and it worked, will surely be useful in the future!